# Python if statement - exclude "--"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm reading data from a netcdf file, I've noticed some fields are written to my file as "--".

When I print the content variable to the console its value is:
 [-33.939999, 151.03918, masked, masked, masked, masked, masked, masked, masked]

I've tried the below code block to check if the row doesn't contain masked or "--" and write those values.  Its not working!

How do I exclude or check for those values?

Tried:
    if "masked" not in content:
        outputwriter.writerow(content)
        print content

**UPDATE**

```
       with open(r'C:/output.csv', 'wb') as csvFile:
        outputwriter = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',')
        for date_val in date_strings:
            header.append(date_val)
        outputwriter.writerow(header)
        for lat_index, lat in enumerate(lats):
            for lon_index, lon in enumerate(lons):
                content = [lat,lon]
                for time_index, time in enumerate(times[:]): 
                    data = value[time_index,lat_index,lon_index]
                    content.append(data)
                #outputwriter.writerow(content) 
                temp = content
                contentVal = (set(temp)-set(exclude))
                for item in contentVal:
                    outputwriter.writerow(item)
                    print item
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset, num2date
import csv

filename = "C:/netcdf.nc"

nc = Dataset(filename, 'r', Format='NETCDF4')

lats = nc.variables['latitude'][:] 
lons = nc.variables['longitude'][:]
sfc = nc.variables['Min_SFC'][:]

times = nc.variables['time']
dates = num2date(times[:],times.units)
date_strings = [date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') for date in dates]

header =  ['Latitude', 'Longitude']
exclude = ['masked','--']

with open(r'C:/output.csv', 'wb') as csvFile:
    outputwriter = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    for date_val in date_strings:
        header.append(date_val)
    outputwriter.writerow(header)
    for lat_index, lat in enumerate(lats):
        for lon_index, lon in enumerate(lons):
            content = [lat,lon]
            for time_index, time in enumerate(times[:]): 
                data = sfc[time_index,lat_index,lon_index]
                content.append(data) 
            contentVal = (set(content)-set(exclude))
            print "Content Val"
            print contentVal
            print "Content"
            print content
            outputwriter.writerow(contentVal)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a for loop.

```
for i in content:
    if i != "masked" or i != "--":
        outputwriter.writerow(i)
        print i
```

Comment: The "--" values are still being written

Comment: try `if i.strip() != "masked" or i.strip() != "--":`

Comment: There's a syntax error
    outputwriter.writerow(i) 
_csv.Error: sequence expected

Comment: if i.strip() != "masked" or i.strip() !="--":
AttributeError: 'numpy.float32' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: `outputwriter.writerow(list(i))`

Comment: outputwriter.writerow(content(i))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `outputwriter`, although if your items are in a list, then it's possible to make another list to exclude values:

```
l = [-33.939999, 151.03918, '--', 'masked', 'masked']
x = ['masked','--']

content = (set(l)-set(x))

for item in content:
    outputwriter.writerow(item)
    print item
```

**Output:**

```
151.03918
-33.939999
```

Comment: If the values are masked or -- I don't want to write any of those values to file.

Comment: I have read the items into the content list [lat, lon, val1, val2, val3] and now if any of the values of content are "--" or masked I don't want to write that row to file. The values in the list are in the correct order for the csv file.

Comment: I'm getting this error -  outputwriter.writerow(item)
_csv.Error: sequence expected.
Question updated with code block

Comment: @Jules0080, Try getting rid of the `for loop` altogether and use `outputwriter.writerow(contentVal)`; I think it's looking for a sequence of values (as in `["item1", "item2"]`, not just a single value at a time `item1`).

Comment: The same error occurs - outputwriter.writerow(contentVal)
_csv.Error: sequence expected

Comment: In your code what is the output of `content`(aka temp) vs. `contentVal`?

Comment: Printing variables to console found:
ContentVal - set([-33.939999, 151.03918, masked])
Content - [-33.939999, 151.03918, masked, masked, masked, masked, masked, masked, masked]

Comment: Something isn't right, because `ContentVal` should not have `set` at the beginning and `masked` is still included. Post the code you've used with `set` including the exclude list, etc.

Comment: Try using it this way -> https://gist.github.com/hmmmph/e3a879c920ee30593a8b. I think it's mainly the `( )` surrounding the `set` command which is the issue.